# Fragment deformation in BottomNavigationActivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image]

I got BottomNavigationActivity and fragment in it. My fragment seems like it has margin on it, but it doesn't. If I stretch it - top part disappears.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `ConstraintLayout` has a `android:paddingTop` . Remove that I can't see it being necessary?

Also your fragment should have:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

But because of your constraints I don't think the `layout_width` and `layout_height` is respected, might even be able to be `0dp` you would need to test if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `ConstraintLayout` as Parent. There is top padding in your layout. remove the padding line from `ConstraintLayout`.

You set a custom height and width for the `Fragment`. Replace the custom size with `match_parent`. That will solve your problem. You can also use `0dp` instead of `match_parent`. `0dp` will automatically resize your fragment window according to the screen size.